# get order collection by product attribute option value in Magento2

Tags: magento2, collection, sales-order

I am trying to fetch full order collection by product attribute option.

I have a "brand" attribute with options "option_1", "option_2", "option_3". This attribute is assigned against each product sku.

I have a written a cron file which triggers everyday.

In that file i need to fetch all the orders where product sku with attribute set as "option_1".

I have used below code to get the order collection for past 2 days.

```
Class Cronfile{

protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;
protected $sortBuilder;
protected $orderRepository;
public function __construct(
 \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrderBuilder $sortBuilder
){
  $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
  $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
  $this->sortBuilder = $sortBuilder;
 }


public function getOrderCollection(){
    $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
      ->addFilter('status','pending','eq')
      ->addSortOrder($this->sortBuilder->setField('entity_id')
      ->setDescendingDirection()->create())
      ->setPageSize(100)->setCurrentPage(1)->create();

    $to = date("Y-m-d h:i:s"); // current date
    $from = strtotime('-2 day', strtotime($to));
    $from = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $from); // 2 days before

    $ordersList = $this->orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
    $ordersList->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$from, 'to'=>$to));
    foreach ($ordersListas $orderItem) {
        echo $orderItem->customerEmail();
   }
}
}
```

**Here i need to fetch all the orders with the product attribute option value.**

can someone help me on this please? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please explain bit more .  You need only attribute value option 1 products order ?

Comment: @Msquare, yes how can we get that,

Comment: If you are getting orderId or IncrementId inside loop the please try to load orderObject too  get Customer email address.

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal, I printed $ordersList->getData() into the log, getting customer email for that but if i use with foreah not working

Comment: Can you please add you entire log print?

Comment: https://tmpfiles.org/download/44575/result , please check here @AbhishekPanchal

Comment: Try `echo $orderItem['customer_email'];`

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal, okay sure will try that, can we filter order collection with the product attribute option? pls update me on that

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal, did you get what i am trying to implement here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106437/discussion-between-abhishek-panchal-and-jafar-pinjar).

Comment: Hi @jafarpinjar please share or add on your  question product Attribute filter code. I have done 70%

Comment: Hi @Msquare, what you want me to add? I have created a attribute called 'brand', which has multiple options, every product associated with some option, pls tell me what I need to add into question?

Comment: Only product filter code.

Comment: @Msquare, I am not added any code for product filter, just created the attribute with options in admin end, sorry i am not clear what you are asking from me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc**

**crontab.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job instance="VendoreName\ModuleName\Cron\Cronfile" method="execute" name="my_cronfile">
            <schedule>*/5 * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Cron**

**Cronfile.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Cron;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Cronfile
{
    protected $logger;
    protected $_orderCollectionFactory;
    protected $orderRepository;
    protected $_customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;  
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->logger->info("my croun run");
        // get all order data
        $order_data = $this->getOrderList();

        foreach ($order_data as $order_key => $order_value) {
            // get order id
            $order_id = $order_value->getIncrementId();

            // get order items
            $order_items = $this->getOrderItems($order_id);
            if (!empty($order_items)) {
                foreach ($order_items->getAllVisibleItems() as $key_items => $value_items) {
                    //get product id
                    $prd_id = $value_items->getId();
                    //filter product collection by id 
                    $prd_data = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
                    $prd_data->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $prd_id);
                    $prd_data->addAttributeToSelect('*');
                    $prd_data->addFieldToFilter('brand', 'option_1'); // set your filter value here 
                    // show your data 
                    //print_r($prd_data->getData());

                    // get order id here 
                    if($prd_data->getData()) {
                        print_r($order_value->getId());
                    }

                }//
            }
        }

        $this->logger->info("my croun over");
    }

    public function getOrderList()
    {
        $order_collection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create();
        $order_collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        return $order_collection;
    }

    public function getOrderItems($order_id)
    {
        return $this->orderRepository->get($order_id);
    }
}
```

> *before run this code please create blank controller and test this code and make your change as your requirement.*

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: tested this I am looking for code to list all the order id's with product attribute has particular option value

Comment: is it working for you? getting Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 792723456 bytes exhausted.

Comment: yes it's works in which line this error come ?

Comment: its not showing the error line number for me compile success, may be issue with foreach loop with large data

Comment: hi @jafarpinjar you need to create an blank controller and add code line by and check everithing.

Comment: Yes @Msquare, moved into controller, checking now

Comment: yes print value check get and set go next line.

Comment: hi, @Msquare I could resolve the error now, but $prd_data->addFieldToFilter('brand', 'option_1'); this is not filtering the product with attribute option, getting empty array